# SQLite select issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written method which should return string with data from select query, but it doesn't work perfectly as I would like, here is method:

```
public String selectorDanych(String kolumna, String log){
String test = "Select "+ kolumna + " from "+ Usr_TABLE+ " where "+colLogin + " ='" +log+"';";
Cursor cursor2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(test, null);
return cursor2.toString();
}
```

it returns some kind of string but, it is not the thing I want [ the string it returns is something like "SQLite.database.@" etc

Comment: Try to upvote the answer pliz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as

```
public String selectorDanych(String kolumna, String log){
    String test = "Select "+ kolumna + " from "+ Usr_TABLE+ " where "+colLogin + " ='" +log+"';";
    Cursor cursor2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(test, null);

//Write these codes
if(cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
   cursor2.close();             //You should close your cursor
   return cursor2.getString(0); //index of your kolumna field
} else {
   cursor2.close();             //You should close your cursor
   return null; //Return some error msg, to notify that data not found
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the internal name of the Cursor you got from the query, not any data from the query results.

You should use something like:

```
cursor2.moveToFirst(); // position the cursor at the first returned row
String col = cursor2.getString(the_index_of_the_column_you_want);
cursor2.close();
return col;
```

Make sure you test for errors though (there might be no rows returned at all), and read the [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) API docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. You may catch exception after the try block. Even if you don't, you're guaranteed that the close() on the cursor will be called! I also suggest to always use English names for your vars.

```
    public String selectorDanych(String kolumna, String log){
    String test = "Select "+ kolumna + " from "+ Usr_TABLE+ " where "+colLogin + " ='" +log+"';";
    Cursor cursor2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(test, null);

  if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.moveToFirst()) { 
      try { //use try - finally to close the cursor in the finally block
        int index_kolumna = cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(kolumna);
        String kolumna_val = cursor2.getString(index_kolumna);  
      } finally { 
        if (cursor2 != null && !cursor2.isClosed()) {
        cursor2.close();
      }
   }
```

}